# Trouble adding search widget to ArcGIS Shortlist Story App

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I 'm having issues adding in a search widget to a shortlist application. I have included the code below. The search bar shows up, but is not functional.
I am needing to have this to where it can search business names that are included within the application.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>ChahtaPreneur</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">

  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

  <link type="image/ico" rel="shortcut icon" href="//resources.esri.com/favicon.ico">
  <link type="image/ico" rel="icon"  href="//resources.esri.com/favicon.ico">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
  
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.2/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/esri/css/esri.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorbox/colorbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/common/helper_functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var djConfig = {parseOnLoad: true};</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.animate-colors-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/"></script>




 
 <style>
  html,body,
  #mapDiv,.map.container{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
  }
     #search {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 20px;
        left: 720px;
      }
</style>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>
 

  <!--
   To correctly reference your Shortlist in search engine:
    - create and fill out extensively an ArcGIS Online item that link to your final application
    - edit the following four tags as well as the title tag above on line 4
  -->
  <meta name="description" content="This story map was created with the Story Map Shortlist application in ArcGIS Online.">

  <!-- Facebook sharing -->
  <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
  <meta property="og:title" content="Story Map Shortlist"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="This story map was created with the Story Map Shortlist application in ArcGIS Online."/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="resources/common/icons/esri-globe.png"/>
 

  <!--
   This application is released under the Apache License V2.0 by Esri http://www.esri.com/
   Checkout the project repository on GitHub to access source code, latest revision, developer documentation, FAQ and tips
   https://github.com/Esri/shortlist-storytelling-template-js
  -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
   //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Application configuration (ignored on ArcGIS Online, Portal and during development)
   //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   var configOptions = {
    // Enter an application ID created through the Shortlist builder
    appid: "f8c9b5d9a2c64703bb72910f46f59d7c",
    // Optionally to secure Shortlist's access, use an OAuth application ID (example: 6gyOg377fLUhUk6f)
    // User will need to sign-in to access the viewer even if your application is public
    oAuthAppId: "",
    // Optionally to be able to use the appid URL parameter, configure here the list of application author
    //  whose application are allowed to be viewed by this Shortlist deployment
    // This is the Portal username of the Shortlist owner (e.g. ["user1"], ["user1", "user2"])
    authorizedOwners: ["*"]
   };
   // Optionally sharing and proxy URLs can be configured in app/config.js. This is only required
   //  when the webmap is not hosted on ArcGIS Online or a Portal for ArcGIS instance and the application isn't deployed as /home/Shortlist/ or /apps/Shortlist/.
   // Optionally Bing Maps key, Geometry and Geocode service's URLs can be configured in app/config.js. This is only required
   //  if the Organization or Portal for ArcGIS instance default configuration has to be overwritten.
  </script>
  
   
<script type="text/javascript">

dojo.require("dijit.dijit");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("esri.map");
dojo.require("esri.arcgis.utils");
dojo.require("esri.dijit.Geocoder");

/******************************************************
********************  config section ******************
*******************************************************/

var WEBMAP_ID = "6b3d1da24e5841f1b8d47de63b7be7a4";
var BOOKMARKS_ALIAS = "Zoom";
var COLOR_ORDER = "green,red,blue,purple"; // will only use as many colors as you have content (point) layers
var BINGMAPS_KEY = "";
     
/******************************************************
******************** app variables ********************
*******************************************************/

 
var _contentLayers = [];

var _isMobile = isMobile();

var _map;

var _bookmarks;

var _layerCurrent;

var _selected;

var _initExtent;

var _dojoReady = false;
var _jqueryReady = false;

var  geocoder;
var locatorUrl = "http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/";

/******************************************************
************************* init ************************
*******************************************************/

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {_dojoReady = true;init()});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {_jqueryReady = true;init()});

/* init comes in two parts because of async call to 
   createMap. */

function init() {
 
 if (!_jqueryReady) return;
 if (!_dojoReady) return;
 
 if (getParameterByName("webmap") != "") {
  WEBMAP_ID = getParameterByName("webmap");
 }
 
 if (getParameterByName("bookmarks_alias") != "") {
  BOOKMARKS_ALIAS = getParameterByName("bookmarks_alias");
 }
 
 if (getParameterByName("color_order") != "") {
  COLOR_ORDER = getParameterByName("color_order")
 } 
 
 $("#bookmarksTogText").html(BOOKMARKS_ALIAS+' &#x25BC;');
 
 $(this).resize(handleWindowResize); 
 
 $("#zoomIn").click(function(e) {
        _map.setLevel(_map.getLevel()+1);
    });
 $("#zoomOut").click(function(e) {
        _map.setLevel(_map.getLevel()-1);
    });
 $("#zoomExtent").click(function(e) {
        _map.setExtent(_initExtent);
    }); 
 
 $(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
  $(".details .rightDiv").height($(".details").height() - 65);
 });  
 
 $("#bookmarksToggle").click(function(){
  if ($("#bookmarksDiv").css('display')=='none'){
    $("#bookmarksTogText").html(BOOKMARKS_ALIAS+' &#x25B2;');
  }
  else{
    $("#bookmarksTogText").html(BOOKMARKS_ALIAS+' &#x25BC;');
  }
  $("#bookmarksDiv").slideToggle();
 });
  
 var mapDeferred = esri.arcgis.utils.createMap(WEBMAP_ID, "map", {
  mapOptions: {
   slider: false,
   wrapAround180:false
  },
  ignorePopups: true,
  bingMapsKey: BINGMAPS_KEY
 });
 
 mapDeferred.addCallback(function(response) {   
  
  document.title = response.itemInfo.item.title;
  $("#title").html(response.itemInfo.item.title);
  $("#subtitle").html(response.itemInfo.item.snippet);
  
  _map = response.map;
    
    //resize the map when the browser resizes
  dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', _map,_map.resize);
  dojo.connect(_map, 'onExtentChange', refreshList);

  // click action on the map where there's no graphic 
  // causes a deselect.

  dojo.connect(_map, 'onClick', function(event){
   if (event.graphic == null) {
    unselect();
   }
  });
  
  _bookmarks = response.itemInfo.itemData.bookmarks;
  if (_bookmarks) {
   loadBookmarks();
   $("#bookmarksCon").show();
  }
  
  var layers = response.itemInfo.itemData.operationalLayers; 
  
  if(_map.loaded){
   initMap(layers);
  } else {
   dojo.connect(_map,"onLoad",function(){
    initMap(layers);
   });
  }
  
 });
 
 mapDeferred.addErrback(function(error) {
   console.log("Map creation failed: ", dojo.toJson(error));
 });
 
}

function initMap(layers) {
 
 var supportLayers = [];
 var pointLayers = [""];
 
 $.each(layers,function(index,value){
  if (value.url == null) {
   if (value.featureCollection.layers[0].featureSet.geometryType == "esriGeometryPoint") {
    pointLayers.push(value);
   } else {
    supportLayers.push(value);
   }
  } else {
   // if the layer has an url property (meaning that it comes from a service), just
   // keep going...it will remain in the map, but won't be query-able.
  }
 });
 
 _initExtent = _map.extent;
 
 var supportLayer;
 $.each(supportLayers,function(index,value) {
  supportLayer = findLayer(_map,value.title);
  if (supportLayer == null) return;
  $.each(supportLayer.graphics,function(index,value) {
   value.attributes.getValueCI = getValueCI; // assign extra method to handle case sensitivity
  });
  dojo.connect(supportLayer, "onMouseOver", baselayer_onMouseOver);
  dojo.connect(supportLayer, "onMouseOut", baselayer_onMouseOut);
  dojo.connect(supportLayer, "onClick", baselayer_onClick);
 });
 
 if (COLOR_ORDER.split(",").length < pointLayers.length) {
  // you have supplied fewer colors than point layers and
  // therefore have lost your sorting privileges...
  colorschemes = COLOR_SCHEMES;
 } else {
  // sort the colors
  var colorschemes = getSortedColorSchemes();
  // burn off any extra colors, if you have more colors
  // than points.
  while (pointLayers.length < colorschemes.length) {
   colorschemes.shift()
  };
 }
 
 var contentLayer;
 $.each(pointLayers,function(index,value) {
  _map.removeLayer(findLayer(_map,value.title));
  if (index <= 4) {  // maximum of 4 point layers.
   $.each(value.featureCollection.layers[0].featureSet.features,function(index,value) {
    value.attributes.getValueCI = getValueCI; // assign extra method to handle case sensitivity
   });
   contentLayer = buildLayer(
      value.featureCollection.layers[0].featureSet.features.sort(SortByID),
      colorschemes[index].iconDir,
      colorschemes[index].iconPrefix
      );
   contentLayer.color = colorschemes[index].color;
   contentLayer.title = value.title;
   dojo.connect(contentLayer, "onMouseOver", layer_onMouseOver);
   dojo.connect(contentLayer, "onMouseOut", layer_onMouseOut);
   dojo.connect(contentLayer, "onClick", layer_onClick);
  
   _map.addLayer(contentLayer);
   _contentLayers.push(contentLayer);
  }
 });
 
 _contentLayers.reverse();
 $.each(_contentLayers,function(index,value){
  $("#tabs").append('<div class="tab" onclick="activateLayer(_contentLayers['+index+'])">'+value.title+'</div>');
 });

 activateLayer(_contentLayers[0]);
 dojo.connect(_map.infoWindow,"onHide",infoWindow_onHide);
 handleWindowResize();
 $("#zoomToggle").css("visibility","visible");
 
// Solomon Additions

  // add a graphics layer for geocoding results
        _map.addLayer(new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer({
          id: "results"
          
       
        }));
  var myGeocoders = [{
             url: locatorUrl,
             name: "Single_Line"
        }];
 // create the geocoder
 geocoder = new esri.dijit.Geocoder({
  autoComplete : true,
  autoNavigate: true,
  localSearchOptions : {
       minScale : 3,
       distance : 4000},
  maxLocations : 20,
   arcgisGeocoder: false,
  geocoders:myGeocoders,
  value:'Search by Name',
  map : _map
 }, "search");
 geocoder.startup();
 geocoder.focus();
 

  var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol({
          "angle":0,
          "xoffset":0,
          "yoffset":10,
          "type":"esriPMS",
          "url":"http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/BluePin1LargeB.png",
          "contentType":"image/png",
          "width":24,
          "height":24
        });
        var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("${NAME}", "${*}");

        dojo.connect(geocoder, "onFindResults", function(response) {

        //STEVE CHANGES

         //Use first match
         //var name = response.results[0].name;

         //Match name with locations layer and selected that index
         //for(i in _locations){
          //if(name === _locations[i].attributes.getName()){
           //preSelection()
           //_selected = _locations[i];
           //postSelection();
          //}
         //}

         //STEVE CHANGES END


          console.log("find results: ", response);
          var l = _map.getLayer("shortlistlayer");
          l.clear();
          _map.infoWindow.hide();
          dojo.forEach(response.results, function(r) {
            r.feature.attributes.NAME = r.NAME;
            r.feature.setSymbol(symbol);
            r.feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
            l.add(r.feature);
          });
          });


// solomon Addition Ends
      

}

/******************************************************
******************** event handlers *******************
*******************************************************/

function tile_onMouseOver(e) {
  $(this).stop().animate({'background-color' : COLOR_FULL});
}

function tile_onMouseOut(e) {
 
 if (_selected != null) {
  // does this tile represent the selected graphic?
  var id = parseInt($(this).attr("id").substring(4));
  if (_selected.attributes.getValueCI("Number") == id) {
   return;
  }
 }
 
 $(this).stop().animate({'background-color' : COLOR_DIM});
}

function tile_onClick(e) {
 // turn off the last selected tile...
 
 if (_selected != null) {
  var tile = $.grep($("ul.tilelist li"),function(n,i){return n.id == "item"+_selected.attributes.getValueCI("Number")})[0];
  if ($(tile).attr("id") != $(this).attr("id")) $(tile).stop().animate({'background-color' : COLOR_DIM});
 } 
 $(this).stop().animate({'background-color' : COLOR_FULL});
 var id= $(this).attr("id").substring(4);
 _selected = $.grep(_layerCurrent.graphics,function(n,i){return n.attributes.getValueCI("Number") == id})[0];
 postSelection();
}

function infoWindow_onHide(event) {
 unselect();
}

function baselayer_onMouseOver(event)
{
 if (_isMobile) return; 
 _map.setMapCursor("pointer");
 var graphic = event.graphic;
 $("#hoverInfo").html(graphic.attributes.getValueCI("Title"));
 var pt = event.screenPoint;
 hoverInfoPos(pt.x,pt.y);
}

function baselayer_onMouseOut(event)
{
 if (_isMobile) return; 
 _map.setMapCursor("default");
 $("#hoverInfo").hide();
}

function baselayer_onClick(event) {
 var feature = event.graphic;
 _map.infoWindow.setTitle(event.graphic.attributes.getValueCI("NAME"));
 _map.infoWindow.setContent(event.graphic.attributes.getValueCI("CAPTION")+"<p><span class='infoWindowLink'>Details >></span></p>");
 _map.infoWindow.show(event.mapPoint); 
 $(".infoWindowLink").click(function(e) {
        showDetails(feature);
    });
 $("#hoverInfo").hide(); 
}

function layer_onClick(event)
{
 var tile;
 if (_selected != null) {
  tile = $.grep($("ul.tilelist li"),function(n,i){return n.id == "item"+_selected.attributes.getValueCI("Number")})[0]
  $(tile).stop().animate({'background-color' : COLOR_DIM});
 } 
 _selected = event.graphic;
 tile = $.grep($("ul.tilelist li"),function(n,i){return n.id == "item"+_selected.attributes.getValueCI("Number")})[0]
 $(tile).stop().animate({'background-color' : COLOR_FULL});
 postSelection();
}

function layer_onMouseOver(event)
{
 if (_isMobile) return;
 _map.setMapCursor("pointer");
 var graphic = event.graphic;
 if (graphic == _selected) return;
 graphic.setSymbol(graphic.symbol.setHeight(30).setWidth(24));
 $("#hoverInfo").html(graphic.attributes.getValueCI("NAME"));
 var pt = _map.toScreen(graphic.geometry);
 hoverInfoPos(pt.x,pt.y);
}

function layer_onMouseOut(event)
{
 if (_isMobile) return; 
 _map.setMapCursor("default");
 var graphic = event.graphic; 
 graphic.setSymbol(graphic.symbol.setHeight(28).setWidth(22));
 $("#hoverInfo").hide();
}


/******************************************************
****************** other functions ********************
*******************************************************/

function unselect() {
 if (_selected != null) {
  tile = $.grep($("ul.tilelist li"),function(n,i){return n.id == "item"+_selected.attributes.getValueCI("Number")})[0]
  $(tile).stop().animate({'background-color' : COLOR_DIM});
 } 
 _selected = null;
 postSelection();
}

// sort items by numeric ID
function SortByID(a, b){
  var aID = a.attributes.getValueCI("Number");
  var bID = b.attributes.getValueCI("Number"); 
  return ((aID < bID) ? -1 : ((aID > bID) ? 1 : 0));
}

function loadBookmarks() {
 
 $.each(_bookmarks,function(index,value){$("#bookmarksDiv").append("<p><a>"+value.name+"</a></p>")});
 
 $("#bookmarksDiv a").click(function(e) {
  var name = $(this).html();
  var extent = new esri.geometry.Extent($.grep(_bookmarks,function(n,i){return n.name == name})[0].extent);
  _map.setExtent(extent); 
  $("#bookmarksTogText").html(BOOKMARKS_ALIAS+' &#x25BC;');
  $("#bookmarksDiv").slideToggle();
    });

}

function activateLayer(layer) {
 _selected = null;
 postSelection();
 _layerCurrent = layer;

 var tab = $.grep($(".tab"),function(n,i){return $(n).html() == _layerCurrent.title})[0];
 $(".tab").removeClass("tab-selected");
 $(tab).addClass("tab-selected");

 $.each(_contentLayers,function(index,value){
  value.setVisibility(value == _layerCurrent);
 });

 $("#myList").empty();
 
 var display;
 var tile;
 var img;
 var footer;
 var num;
 var title;
 
 $.each(_layerCurrent.graphics,function(index,value){
  if (_map.extent.contains(value.geometry)) {
   display = "visible"
  } else {
   display = "none";
  }
  tile = $('<li id="item'+value.attributes.getValueCI("Number")+'" style="display:'+display+'">');
  img = $('<img src="'+value.attributes.getValueCI("THUMB_URL")+'">');
  footer = $('<div class="footer"></div>');
  num = $('<div class="num" style="background-color:'+_layerCurrent.color+'">'+value.attributes.getValueCI("Number")+'</div>');
  title = $('<div class="blurb">'+value.attributes.getValueCI("Name")+'</div>');
  $(footer).append(num);
  $(footer).append(title);
  $(tile).append(img);
  $(tile).append(footer);
  $("#myList").append(tile);
 });
 
 // event handlers have to be re-assigned every time you load the list...
 $("ul.tilelist li").mouseover(tile_onMouseOver);
 $("ul.tilelist li").mouseout(tile_onMouseOut);
 $("ul.tilelist li").click(tile_onClick); 
 
 $("ul.tilelist").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, { duration: 200 } );
 
}

function refreshList() {
 var tile;
 $.each(_layerCurrent.graphics,function(index,value){
  //find the corresponding tile
  tile = $.grep($("ul.tilelist li"),function(n,i){return n.id == "item"+value.attributes.getValueCI("Number")})[0];
  if (_map.extent.contains(value.geometry)) {
   if ($(tile).css("display") == "none") $(tile).stop().fadeIn();
  } else {
   if ($(tile).css("display") != "none") $(tile).stop().fadeOut(1000);
  }  
 });
}

function buildLayer(arr,iconDir,root) {
 var layer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
 var pt;
 var sym;
 $.each(arr,function(index,value){
  pt = new esri.geometry.Point(value.geometry.x,value.geometry.y,value.geometry.spatialReference);
  sym = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("images/icons/"+iconDir+"/"+root+value.attributes.getValueCI("Number")+".png",22,28);
  layer.add(new esri.Graphic(pt,sym,value.attributes));
 });
 return layer;
}

function getValueCI(field) {
 var found;
 $.each(this,function(index,value){
  if (index.toUpperCase() == field.toUpperCase()) {
   found = index;
   return false;
  }
 });
 return this[found]; 
}

function handleWindowResize() {
 
 var heightDoc = getViewportDimensions()[1];
 
 $("#mainWindow").height(heightDoc - ($("#header").height()));
 dijit.byId("mainWindow").layout();
 $("#paneLeft").height($("#mainWindow").height() - 35);
 $(".tilelist").height($("#paneLeft").height() - 20);
 $("#map").height($("#mainWindow").height() - 35);
```

Comment: Please do try to create a minimal example that reproduces the issue (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: add your working code here without search widget.. we can tell you the steps of adding search widget.. that will be easier...

Comment: not able to see output because in script tag you are passing local source path...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I went though your code the major error i can see is that multiple define error.

[image]

> **Root Cause:**

The main reason for it you are loading those libraries more than once who expose define.

> **Solution:**

- In your case i noticed you have loaded ArcGIS JS Api more than once.
- Just load only one source of ArcGIS it should work.
- One more thinh in attached code you are using multiple versions of CSS.
- you are suppose to use same version of ESRI CSS which you are using for JS.
- As per your code you are using [legacy model of coding style](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/loader/legacy.html) so go for `arcgis js api's` that version only.

**Code without multiple define error:** https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/362ft9g7/

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Answer (score 0):

Well, Here is the working code for esri search widget.

Just require the needed libraries and plugin the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Search with Suggestion Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #search {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 20px;
      left: 74px;
    }
  </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>
  <script>


    require([
        "esri/map", "esri/dijit/Search", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",  "esri/InfoTemplate", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function (Map, Search, FeatureLayer,InfoTemplate) {
      var map = new Map("map", {
        basemap: "gray",
        center: [-82.93, 42.5], // lon, lat
        zoom: 10
      });

      var search = new Search({
        sources: [{
          featureLayer: new FeatureLayer("https://services.arcgis.com/b6gLrKHqgkQb393u/arcgis/rest/services/TaxParcelQuery/FeatureServer/0", {
            outFields: ["*"],
            infoTemplate: new InfoTemplate("Parcels", "Owner name: ${OWNERNME1}</br>Parcel ID: ${PARCELID}</br>Site address: ${SITEADDRESS}")
          }),
          outFields: ["OWNERNME1","PARCELID","SITEADDRESS"],
          displayField: "OWNERNME1",
          suggestionTemplate: "${PARCELID}: ${SITEADDRESS}",
          name: "Parcels",
          placeholder: "example: Shawn Smith",
          enableSuggestions: true
      }],
        map: map
      }, "search");


      search.startup();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="search"></div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***