# how to resolve defineAlreadyDefined issue in dgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, dojo, dgrid

we are working on a one page website project which wad already build in jquery and javascript at client side and cake php at service side but one for grid we want to use DGRID of dojo framework and for that when we try to integrate dgrid with our project we are getting this error

> defineAlreadyDefined

In case we try to open another module because the content coming from AJAX and updated in same page.

We had included `dojo.js` in main page which loads only once and module included with require in each individual file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this happens when we use two or more different libraries which expose same **define** method to create new widgets.

**solution:**

in our project we modified the name of exposed value like instead of define we replaced the **customDefine** in other widget so if we need define of first library we use **define** (as it was earlier) and if we need define of second library basically we used **customDefine**.

**Note:-** Before making above changed just verify that you are not adding same or similar libraries more than once in your project. In our project we were using dojo and d3 libraries.

This is how we resolved in our project.

*Problem with almost similar solution -* [Trouble adding search widget to ArcGIS Shortlist Story App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780405/trouble-adding-search-widget-to-arcgis-shortlist-story-app/39784336#39784336)

[image]

***hoping this will help you:)***